# Why is my incline bench the same with dumbbells as it is with the barbel

Tags: bench-press, dumbbells, chest, barbell

I have heard that your bench press should be around 15% weaker with dumbbells as it is with the barbell. This pretty much holds true for my flat bench. All these stats are for sets of 6: for incline bench, my barbel figure is 70kg but my dumbell figure is 35kg's which is the same. For reference my flat barbell is 100Kg and dumbells is 40Kg's.

For my incline bench am I too weak with the barbell or just stronger than usual with the dumbells?

Comment: At these values, it can well come down to "better neuromuscular adaptation", ie. you simply learned the move better. Which of the two have you done more volume with?

Comment: If you mean volume per exercise, I do the same amount of sets and reps whether I'm using dumbbells or barbel. If you meant volume of each exercise then you're probably because I've always preferred dumbell incline and therefore use that movement more often. I've just always thought that regardless of the use of more stabilising muscles and varied forearm rotation, they would still progress similarly as they use the same major muscle.

Comment: In lower weights, most of your "strength" gain is due to learning the movement better (improvement of inter- and intramuscular coordination) rather than actual hypertrophy. That's why I asked: It could well be your neuromuscular system is just more used to the dumbbells.